# How to serialize ExpandoObject using ServiceStack JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, expandoobject, servicestack

Is it possible to get the ServiceStack JsonSerializer to serialize an ExpandoObject as a flat object rather than a dictionary? Something roughly approximate to this:

```
{"x":"xvalue","y":"\/Date(1313966045485)\/"}
```

I am trying to compare JSON serialization of `ExpandoObject` using three different systems: the .NET BCL JavaScriptSerializer, Newtonsoft JSON.NET, and ServiceStack's JSON offering.

I start with a fairly simple dynamic object.

```
dynamic test = new ExpandoObject();
test.x = "xvalue";
test.y = DateTime.Now;
```

It seems simpler for a serializer to treat an ExpandoObject as a `IDictionary<string, object>`. Both BCL and ServiceStack start off this way, though going fairly different routes with the result.

```
JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Console.WriteLine(javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(test));
// [{"Key":"x","Value":"xvalue"},{"Key":"y","Value":"\/Date(1313966045485)\/"}]

Console.WriteLine(ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(test));
// ["[x, xvalue]","[y, 8/21/2011 16:59:34 PM]"]
```

I would prefer to have ExpandoObject serialized more as it is assembled in code, like a typical class would be serialized. You can [add an override JavaScript serializer to the BCL system for `IDictionary<string, object>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156664/how-to-flatten-an-expandoobject-returned-via-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc/5913094#5913094). This works great, assuming one doesn't actually have a `IDictionary<string, object>` that needs to stay that way (which I don't yet).

```
JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
javaScriptSerializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new ExpandoJsonConverter() });
Console.WriteLine(javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(test));
// {"x":"xvalue","y":"\/Date(1313966045485)\/"}
```

Unfortunately, I still need a way to get ServiceStack's JsonSerializer to treat an ExpandoObject in the same fashion. How do I hook into the ServiceStack system to make this possible?

**Update:** While it isn't an option for my uses, it looks like ServiceStack handles anonymous objects just fine.

```
Console.WriteLine(ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(new { x = "xvalue", y = DateTime.Now }));
// {"x":"xvalue","y":"\/Date(1313980029620+0000)\/"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any hooks available in ServiceStack's JsonSerializer that you can plug into to change this behaviour but I'm be more than happy to take a pull request that does it ;)

The classes you will need to change are:

- [JsWriter.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/JsWriter.cs#L223) (Line 223) - insert code to detect an expando object and return a delegate that writes the expando object how you want it.
- [JsReader](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/JsReader.cs#L42) (Line 42) - insert code to detect an expando object and return a delegate to read the contents of a string and deserialize it back into an expando

I imagine the code for dealing with an expando object is similar to a dictionary so you should be able to use the Dictionary implementation classes to guide you (i.e. [WriteDictionary.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/WriteDictionary.cs) and [DeserializeDictionary.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/DeserializeDictionary.cs))

Feel free to use the ServiceStack forum if you have any more questions/issues on this: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/servicestack

Comment: If I can get MonoTouch to use ServiceStack to deserialize JSON generated from one of the other systems, this specific problem won't actually hurt me too much. Even if I can work around it, I will try to see what I can do to put together some code for a pull request; it would be nice to use ServiceStack on both ends of my current project.

Comment: Sure, to get ServiceStack working on MonoTouch you just need to use the MonoTouch build which is available at: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/release/latest/MonoTouch

Comment: That was easy. I had it up and running in a few minutes. It would have been seconds if I wasn't relearning keyboard shortcuts in MonoDevelop as I went.