# What is the best way to unit test a simple JsonResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, expandoobject

In the event of a successful AJAX call I want to return a simple object with `Success = true`

```
public ActionResult Foo(int id)
{
    // ...
    return Json(new {Success=true});
}
```

This works fine and the object my javascript receives looks like

```
{ Success : true }
```

but because the object returned is an anonymous type, I can't do (something like) the following in my test:

```
var result = (JsonResult)controller.AddNote(id, message);
dynamic data = result.Data;

// Assert
Assert.That(data.Success, Is.EqualTo(true));
```

So I tried returning an ExpandoObject which allows the test to work in the way I want but the the JSON sent back in the AJAX response is a mess, [as detailed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156664/how-to-flatten-an-expandoobject-returned-via-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc).

```
[{"Key":"Success","Value":true}]
```

Is there a simple, clean way to achieve what seems like it should be easy, or is the only way to implement some custom serialization as in the linked question?

Comment: The result.Data you get in your unit test can not contain the json data because the jsonResult serializer is only run in the ExecuteResult method which is not run in a unit test. The "data" in your result.Data is just the anonymous data you assigned in your AddNote/Foo action. What you test is not json data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the value with `dynamic` can work if you mark your controller assembly with the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestsProject")]`. Because the classes generated for anonymous types are internal and runtime binding does not work with internal types. In this [article](http://www.heartysoft.com/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic) you can find more information about this.
2. If you don't like this approach you can fallback to plain old reflection (hidden behind some helper methods):

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void AddNote1()
   {
       ...
       var result = ((JsonResult)controller.AddNote(id, message));
       var data = result.Data;

       // Assert
       Assert.AreEqual(Get<bool>(data, "Success"), true);
    }

    private T Get<T>(object instance, string propertyName)
    {
        return (T) instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
    }
   ```
3. Use named classes instead of anonymous ones.
4. You have to use some kind of serialization workaround as you mentioned.

Comment: `InternalsVisibleTo` Legendary!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var response = new { id = 0, Status = false };
dynamic object = js.Deserialize(new StringReader(JSONText), response.GetType());

Assert.IsTrue(object.Success)
```

What this does is:

1. Create a JavaScriptSerializer.
2. Create a new anonymous object with the same layout as your json, so the serialiser knows what your object looks like
3. Deserialize the json into a new dynamic object.

The disadvantage of this is that you will not have IntelliSense on your json object, so any spelling mistake will not be caught by the compiler.

*Note: I wrote the code here in stackoverflow, so there might be minor bugs in it. I did not test it, but it should work :P*

Comment: Where would you get `JSONText` from? In the unit test, you don't have the actual HTTP body that goes over the wire...