# How do I flatten a JSON response from IEnumerable<dynamic>?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, massive

I am using Rob Conery's excellent masssive micro ORM in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

When I query using massive the return type from the Query method is `IEnumerable<dynamic>` which returns JSON in a verbose format.

```
var contacts = _contacts.Query("SELECT [ContactID], [FirstName], [LastName], ISNULL([Title],'') AS [Title] FROM Contacts");
return Json(contacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

returns....

```
[[{"Key":"ContactID","Value":"304830"},{"Key":"FirstName","Value":"Manhee"},{"Key":"LastName","Value":"Kim"},{"Key":"Title","Value":"Manager"}],[{"Key":"ContactID","Value":"304880"},{"Key":"FirstName","Value":"Usman"}, etc....
```

I want the format to exclude the verbose key value format and look like ...

```
{"ContactID":"304830"},{"FirstName":"Manhee"},{"LastName","Kim"},etc...
```

I thought dynamic objects did this by default, but am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flatten an ExpandoObject returned via JsonResult in asp.net mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156664/how-to-flatten-an-expandoobject-returned-via-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: You are right. Looked into massive and the dynamic object is from a new ExpandoObject. Thanks!

Comment: Just give ToList() to your result, to convert ExpandoQuery to ExpandoObjectCollection, that will help. After that convert to JSON. That will work.