# How do I make WebMethods serialize ExpandoObject

Tags: asp.net, json, asmx, expandoobject

I have a WebMethod that looks like this which is used to populate a jqGrid

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyWebService: System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public object GetPeople(bool _search, double nd, int rows, int page, string sidx, string sord)
    {
        var tbl = new DynamicModel("ConnStr", tableName: "Person", primaryKeyField: "ID");
        var results = tbl.Paged(orderBy: sidx + " " + sord, currentPage: page, pageSize: rows);
        return results;
    }

}
```

"results" is a System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject with the properties Items, TotalPages, TotalRecords

The json I get back on the from the webservice looks like this

```
{
"d": [{
    "Key": "TotalRecords",
    "Value": 1
}, {
    "Key": "TotalPages",
    "Value": 1
}, {
    "Key": "Items",
    "Value": [
        [{
            "Key": "Row",
            "Value": 1
        }, {
            "Key": "ID",
            "Value": 1
        }, {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "Test Template"
        }]
    ]
}]
}
} // Don't know why firebug put this extra bracket
```

Ideally I'd prefer that it comes back without all the Key and Value business as it bloats out the json unnecessarily and doesn't play nicely with jqGrid.

Is there a way to change the way ASP.NET is handling the serialization of the ExpandoObject?

Comment: A friend recommended this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156664/how-to-flatten-an-expandoobject-returned-via-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc but I don't know how to register the JavaScriptConverter with the JavaScriptSerializer that the webmethod uses.

Comment: Damn, the answer I seek is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183.aspx about half way down

Comment: Good to know that you learnt something new :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you've already figured this out, but here's [something I threw together a while back](https://gist.github.com/6cfcdfdf2a117fa5e81b) to do just that:

```
public class ExpandoObjectConverter : JavaScriptConverter {
  public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes {
    get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type>(new Type[] { typeof(ExpandoObject) })); }
  }

  public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) {
    ExpandoObject expando = (ExpandoObject)obj;

    if (expando != null) {
      // Create the representation.
      Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in expando) {
        if (item.Value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
          result.Add(item.Key, ((DateTime)item.Value).ToShortDateString());
        else
          result.Add(item.Key, item.Value.ToString());
      }

      return result;
    }
    return new Dictionary<string, object>();
  }

  public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then, you just need to add it to the `<converters>` section in your web.config, as shown in the MSDN article you linked to:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization>
          <converters>
            <add name="ExpandoObjectConverter" type="ExpandoObjectConverter"/>
          </converters>
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yeah, hopefully this helps someone else. Although the <jsonSerialization /> should be <jsonSerialization> shame on MSDN. Thanks for your quick reply Dave, love the work, love the tekpub vids

Comment: @SeanTomlins: Ack, there's what I get for blindly trusting MSDN! Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my answer and pinged someone at MS to hopefully get that error fixed.

Comment: Works great except when the Value is null.  Added a check for it and works fine.

`foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in expando)
                {
                    if (item.Value == null)
                        result.Add(item.Key, string.Empty);
                    else if (item.Value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                        result.Add(item.Key, ((DateTime)item.Value).ToShortDateString());
                    else
                        result.Add(item.Key, item.Value.ToString());
                }`