# Dynamic model with Telerik ASP MVC

Tags: dynamic, telerik-mvc, reflection.emit, expandoobject, dynamicobject

Has anyone found a way to dynamically create a grid using ExpandoObject, DynamicObject or Reflection.Emit and at the same time allow CRUD operations?

I was able to use Reflection.Emit to dynamically create my grid columns and display data, but once I try to edit a row, the cell contents disappear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a project showing how to use dynamic objects with Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC. You can find it here: http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/binding-to-a-collection-of-dynamic-objects-with-mvc3-razor.aspx

Comment: Have you tried this with `ExpandoObject` or the like? I am experiencing the same problem as @JoBot right now:
After binding the grid to `dynamic` (`ExpandoObject`) via AJAX, the rows are there, but all cells are empty, even though the returned JSON data looks alright.
Could the problem be that those objects are serialized as in a Key-Value structure instead of a "real" JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5913094/11963) code. The normal `JavaScriptSerializer` that's used by ASP.NET MVC to produce the JSON output serializes `ExpandoObject` similarly `IDictionary<string, object>`, so that instead of the required JSON object, the `data` array actually contains a list of key-value pairs, which the Telerik ASP.NET MVC grid cannot work with.

Comment: Sorry for being MIA since my first post, but I got pulled into a completely different project.
In any case... @hangy thank you for the suggestion.  You are right on spot with the key-value pairs that Telerik's MVC grid cannot handle when using ExpandoObject.
As for my original post regarding the missing cell values when modifying rows, it turned out that I made a silly mistake of not adding the template that the grid will be using in \EditorTemplates.