# Serializing ExpandoObject with ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#, .net, json, servicestack

I am trying to serialize objects with the library [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) . This works

```
using System.Dynamic;
using ServiceStack.Text;
var x = new {Value= 10, Product = "Apples"};                
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(x));
```

I get, as I expect

```
{"Value":10,"Product":"Apples"}
```

However

```
dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
x.Value = 100;
x.Product = "Apples";
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(x));
```

I get to my surprise

```
[{"Key":"Value","Value":100},{"Key":"Product","Value":"Apples"}]
```

Why! What's going on?

**Secondly**, *how can I get what I want?*

Comment: It looks like the serializer is misunderstanding your data structure... could you post the structure?

Comment: If you install ServiceStack.Text you should be able to run my code above (repeating the using statements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ExpandoObject` implements `IConnection<KeyValuePair>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`:

```
public sealed class ExpandoObject :
    IDynamicMetaObjectProvider,
    IDictionary<string, object>,
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>,
    IEnumerable, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

My guess is that internally, the ServiceStack serializer is treating the `ExpandoObject` as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`, and so it serializes to a JSON array of key/value pairs.

---

This differs from your first (working) code snippet because .NET actually builds a real (anonymous) class for your data, basically it makes:

```
public class SomeNameTheCompilerMakesUp {
    internal int Value { get; set; }
    internal string Product { get; set; }
}
```

for you automatically, so when it is sent to the serializer, it is working with a real class with real properties, whereas the `ExpandoObject` is really backed by an `object[]` internally.

---

On a side-note, Microsoft's `System.Web.Helpers.Json` behaves the same way. This test passes:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ExpandoObjectSerializesToJsonArray()
    {
        dynamic anonType = new { Value = 10, Product = "Apples" };

        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
        expando.Value = 10;
        expando.Product = "Apples";

        var anonResult = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(anonType);
        var expandoResult = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(expando);

        Assert.AreEqual("{\"Value\":10,\"Product\":\"Apples\"}", anonResult);
        Assert.AreEqual("[{\"Key\":\"Value\",\"Value\":10},{\"Key\":\"Product\",\"Value\":\"Apples\"}]", expandoResult);
    }
```

---

***One final edit:***

You can make this work the way you want by turning your `ExpandoObject` into a `Dictionary<string, object>`. The caveat to this code is that it duplicates the data into a dictionary, so you have 2 copies in memory (or slightly less than, since technically the strings might be interned).

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
        expando.Value = 10;
        expando.Product = "Apples";

        // copy expando properties to dictionary
        var dictionary = ((ExpandoObject)expando).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        var expandoResult    = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(expando);
        var dictionaryResult = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(dictionary);

        Assert.AreEqual("[{\"Key\":\"Value\",\"Value\":10},{\"Key\":\"Product\",\"Value\":\"Apples\"}]", expandoResult);
        Assert.AreEqual("{\"Value\":10,\"Product\":\"Apples\"}", dictionaryResult);
    }
```

Although, for anyone that comes across this later, and is actually using `System.Web.Helpers.Json`, the better thing to do is just wrap your `ExpandoObject` in a `DynamicJsonObject` like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
        expando.Value = 10;
        expando.Product = "Apples";

        var dictionaryResult = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(new DynamicJsonObject(expando));

        Assert.AreEqual("{\"Value\":10,\"Product\":\"Apples\"}", dictionaryResult);
    }
```

Ans once I worked through that, I found a similar question here: [How to flatten an ExpandoObject returned via JsonResult in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156664/how-to-flatten-an-expandoobject-returned-via-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks Rally, this makes sense. Any idea how can serialize ExpandoObject the way I want?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't.  I tried `System.Web.Helpers.Json` hoping that it would work the way you wanted, and was going to propose that as an alternative, but it does the same thing. :)

Comment: @MattHickford - scratch my previous comment. I added a possible solution at the end of my answer.

Comment: I know it's been a while but I can't tell you how useful your final solution is for me :) Thanks!