# Appending properties to an anonymous type for use with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am extending `JsonResult` and need to add properties to the `Data` property within it.

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    // error checking removed for brevity

    this.Data = AppendSomehow(
                    this.Data, // = new { hello = "hi" }
                    new { goodbye = "bye" });

    base.ExecuteResult(context); // calls javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(this.Data)
}
```

One option is to convert it into an `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
private static object AppendSomehow(object data, object additional)
{
    var originalDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(original);
    var additionalDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(additional);

    foreach (var kv in additionalDictionary)
        originalDictionary.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);

    return originalDictionary;
}
```

but when passed through a `JavaScriptSerializer` this will come out as:

```
[{"Key":"hello","Value":"hi"},{"Key":"goodbye","Value":"bye"}]
```

when the desired result is:

```
{"hello":"hi","goodbye":"bye"}
```

I could just copy-paste the `base.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext)` implementation and modify it to use the solution posted in [How to flatten an ExpandoObject returned via JsonResult in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156664/how-to-flatten-an-expandoobject-returned-via-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc/5913094#5913094) but that seems a bit dirty when the implemenation already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going down the `IDictionary<string, object>` route is actually a good way to go as `JavaScriptSerializer` actually serializes `Dictionary<string, object>` correctly. As such all you need to do is take the `IDictionary<string, object>` and instantiate a new concrete `Dictionary<string, object>` with it.

```
private static object AppendSomehow(object data, object additional)
{
    var originalDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(original);
    var additionalDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(additional);

    foreach (var kv in additionalDictionary)
        originalDictionary.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);

    return new Dictionary<string, object>(originalDictionary);
}
```