# Dynamic/Expando and JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

There's a lot of Qs on this, but I need a solution without JSON.Net, etc. - I must use the canned stuff in Asp.Net MVC.

How can I serialize a POCO with a dynamic property - and get all the static properties, too?  What I found was the dynamic only, or the static type which is easy.

e.g.

```
public class ReturnThisClassAsJSON {
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ContainedClass ContainedContents { get; set; }
}

public class ContainedClass {
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public dynamic DynamicInfo { get; set; }
    public List<dynamic> DynamicList { get; set }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample data and the expected serialized JSON output?

Comment: What do you mean by _What I found was the dynamic only, or the static type which is easy._?  Do you have some code that you tried and did not work?  Can you share it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156664/how-to-flatten-an-expandoobject-returned-via-jsonresult-in-asp-net-mvc.  A class with *both* dynamic and static types is what I'm trying to do.  Any object hierarchy of static types is easy.  Throw dynamics into the POCOs and still make it work.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer:

I replaced the dynamic from the DynamicInfo and DynamicList from the ContainedClass with static types.

With the dynamic, I had 1 of 2 choices.  Either serialize the dynamic to a string in its own serialization call using above SO question 5156664. (Which left me with the rest of the class I also wanted serialized and merged with it, thus this question).  Or, incur this error:

"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection .RuntimeModule' ".

when attempting a single serialization call on the ContainedClass.

So, I transferred the dynamics into static-typed classes:

```
public class ColumnValue 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class DynamicRow 
{
    public List<ColumnValue> ColumnValue { get; set; }
}
```

and, change ContainedClass to this:

```
public class ContainedClass
{
    public List<ColumnValue> DynamicInfo { get; set; }
    public List<DynamicRow>  Data { get; set; }
}
```

And, it serializes using out-of-the-box Asp.Net MVC:

```
 return Json(ReturnThisClassAsJSON, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```